# Creating and populating a table is slow and unstable

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

When using `csv_copy` to create/populate a table, I notice it is extremely slow sometimes. The following are the core code and some sample outputs.

I have two questions:

1. I can't figure out why the time varies for creating and populating tables.
2. I am not sure what caused the "none" to be printed.

Code:

```
def create_populate_table(table_name,fields,types,cur):
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + table_name + ' (\n'
    for i in xrange(len(fields)):
        if i==0:
            sql += fields[i]+' '+types[i]+' NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,\n'
        elif i==len(fields)-1:
            sql += fields[i]+' '+types[i]+')'
        else:
            sql += fields[i]+' '+types[i]+',\n'
    #print sql
    cur.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    print "Table ",table_name," created ",timer()

    cur.execute("SELECT count(*) from "+table_name)
    if cur.fetchone()[0]>0:
        return
    # populate data into created table
    fr= open(file, 'r')
    fr.readline()
    # parse and convert data into unicode
    #data = unicode_csv_reader(fr, delimiter='|')
    # anything can be used as a file if it has .read() and .readline() methods
    data = StringIO.StringIO()
    s=''.join(fr.readlines())
    while(s.find('\r\n')<>-1):
        s=s.replace('\r\n','\n')
    #timer()
    while(s.find('||')<>-1 or s.find('|\n')<>-1 ):
        s=s.replace('||','|0|')
        s=s.replace('|\n','|0\n')
    #timer()
    #print s.split('\t')[:2]
    #exit(0)
    data.write(s)
    data.seek(0)
    try:
        cur.copy_from(data, table_name,sep='|')
        conn.commit()
        print "Table ",table_name," populated ",timer()
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        if conn:
            conn.rollback()
        print 'Error %s' % e    
    fr.close()
```

The outputs I see:

> ME_Features_20121001.txt Table  ME_Features_20121001  created  1.44s
>   None Table  ME_Features_20121001  populated  1.48s None
>
> FM_Features_20121001.txt Table  FM_Features_20121001  created  67.92s
>   None Table  FM_Features_20121001  populated  0.22s None
>
> NationalFile_20121001.txt (700mb) Table  NationalFile_20121001 
>   created  9.34s None Table  NationalFile_20121001  populated  4963.18s
>   None
>
> NJ_Features_20121001.txt Table  NJ_Features_20121001  created  1.65s
>   None Table  NJ_Features_20121001  populated  41.11s None
>
> PW_Features_20121001.txt Table  PW_Features_20121001  created  1.73s
>   None Table  PW_Features_20121001  populated  0.20s None

Comment: Do you have to use your own home grown python importer? Can you make use of Postgre copy command?

Comment: @JustBob The code above *does* use the `COPY` command. That's what the `cur.copy_from` line does; it's using a Psycopg2 cursor to run `COPY ... FROM stdin`.

Comment: If you measure the server-side durations (see PostgreSQL manual, `log_min_duration_statement` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html), do they match what your client sees? In general, I would expect the time required to be roughly proportional to the number of records in the CSV file and to its on-disk size. That slow `CREATE TABLE` is a sign you might have slow checkpoints; see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logging_Checkpoints and http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: @CraigRinger see my answer below, I really believe OP is not measuring the time properly, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How is `timer()` defined? My blind guess (as you didn't provide its code) is that this function calls `print` directly to output the measured time, but doesn't return anything explicitly - hence `None` is printed. If it's still unclear, look at the example below:

```
>>> def test():
...     print 'test'
... 
>>> print 'This is a', test()
This is a test
None
```

I'm not sure what you mean saying that *the time varies for creating and populating tables*. Time needed to populate the table depends on the amount of data to insert, obviously. Time needed to create a table should be more or less the same in each case, so the `67.92s` output looks suspicious indeed, but... are you sure it's measured properly?

Again, my blind guess is that `timer()` prints the time since last call. Perhaps you should explicitly reset it before starting the operation you want to measure? I guess that those 60 seconds were spent before calling `create_populate_table()`...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will check the time() function and get back to you.